# How to animate the svg path only forward?

Tags: jquery, css, animation, svg

I need help to animate this svg only forward, right now it's doing forward and backwards like in the codepen.

https://codepen.io/victoreugen2002/pen/oNYGyBY

```
.path.active {
  stroke-dasharray: 200;
  stroke-dashoffset: 200;
  animation: dash 2s linear alternate infinite;
}

@keyframes dash {

  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: remove infinite?

Comment: If I remove infinite, it's disappearing after the animation is completed.

Comment: add forwards ...

Comment: Change infinite to `forwards`